# NHibernate Mapping Dictionary to Multiple Tables

Tags: nhibernate

I recently ran into a problem with using nhibernate mapping dictionaries to particular relation model.
The OO side include entities as follows

```
class B // base class
{
    public long Id;
    public string Name;
    public Owner; // a reference to the owner group
}

class Group : B
{
    public IDictionary<string, B> ObjectsInGroup; 
        // dictionary for a look-up from name of any object contained in the group 
        // to the object itself
}
```

and I wanted to use the following tables to persist the above entities

column definition of table B for holding entities of type B:

- Id: bigint (primary key)
- Name: nvarchar(50)
- Owner: bigint (related to Id as foreign key)

column definition of table G for holding entities of type Group:

- Id: bigint (primary key)

As the objects in the group are managed in a dictionary, and dictionary based mapping of nhibernate is intended to be used, I suppose the actual table on which the mapping is based is extracted from table B. as the standard table underpinning a dictionary mapping is in the following form:

**Id (of the dictionary provider) | Key | Value**

where each line represents a key-value pair in the dictionary of entity with identifier 'Id'.

So basically the imaginary table in such a form to enable the mapping can be created by following SQL (just to give some idea or clarify the question):

**select g.Id, o.Name, o.Id 
from G g, B o
where o.Owner = g.Id**

This is somehow a simplified model, the original one might have a separate class for leaf objects which may have an additional table involved making the problem even worse.

Not sure whether NHibernate actually supports such a mapping or if there some some workarounds or a need to redesign the model. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is not the mapping but the model.
Logically, I think having a collection of `B`s in your `Group` class would make more sense.
(`IEnumerable<B> ObjectsInGroup`)
Searching by an object's name can be done easily with LINQ `ObjectsInGroup.Where(b => b.Name == "blah");`.
That way your mapping is much simpler, and your class is more understandable.

Comment: thanks. yeah, maybe you are right. just not quite sure if done this way i'll again have performance issues when searching by name since there may be large number of objects in the group.

Comment: @Linc Yu: if you have a large number of objects, your performance issues would arise from fetching that large collection from your DB; not from in-memory searches. For searching I would recommend querying, which nHibernate supports very nicely.